# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 121: invalid start byte

Tags: python, csv, utf-8

How do I resolve this issue? Thank you.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Meteo.csv"

Meteo = pd.read_csv(path, parse_dates=[['Date', 'Time']])
Meteo.head()
```

[Sample of CSV](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aT68NkfeeykyLyXkqtehRgmSFmL-_TsA/view?usp=share_link)

I'm looking for help to fix the error because I cannot get the output display yet.

Comment: Please post a sample of your csv and paste the code in your question, not pictures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `encoding='latin-1`

```
df = pd.read_csv('Meteo.csv', encoding='latin-1', parse_dates=[['DATE', 'TIME']])
print(df)

            DATE_TIME TEMPERATURE DEW POINT HUMIDITY WIND WIND SPEED WIND GUST  PRESSURE PRECIPITATION CONDITION
0 2022-01-01 00:00:00       77 °F     72 °F     83 %  VAR      2 mph     0 mph  29.79 in        0.0 in      Fair
1 2022-01-01 01:00:00       75 °F     72 °F     89 %  VAR      1 mph     0 mph  29.79 in        0.0 in      Fair
2 2022-01-01 02:00:00       75 °F     72 °F     89 %    N      3 mph     0 mph  29.79 in        0.0 in      Fair
3 2022-01-01 03:00:00       75 °F     72 °F     89 %    N      3 mph     0 mph  29.76 in        0.0 in      Fair
4 2022-01-01 04:00:00       75 °F     72 °F     89 %  VAR      3 mph     0 mph  29.76 in        0.0 in      Fair
```

Comment: Resolved, thanks. Next code after that also got me into another issue "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'DatetimeArray' and 'str'"

[code]
`Dataset = pd.read_csv('Meteo.csv', encoding='latin-1', parse_dates=[['DATE', 'TIME']])
print(Dataset)
Solar = pd.read_excel(Dataset + "Demand.xlsx")
Solar.head()`
[xlsx data] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o00k7aqoa9AWvG-VVcTzN0TqT82ocgHO/edit?usp=share_link&ouid=113725198561674157107&rtpof=true&sd=true)